How to wire 16 heaters 2 phase in 3 phase 220 with SSR?
I appreciate your help. I'm a mechanical engineer and I have several doubts about this project.
I want to heat a water tank using 16 heaters. The heaters are 5 kW @ 220V, 2-phase each, for a total of 70 kW. The heaters are divided into two groups, with 8 heaters on one side and 8 heaters on the other side of the tank. Each group of 8 heaters is further divided into 3 heaters for low power mode and all 8 heaters for high power mode. I have a temperature controller for this setup.
My main question is if I can connect my electric heaters as shown in the attached diagram. Specifically, I want to know if I can use a three-pole SSR (solid state relay) to power 3 two-phase 220V heaters, and another three-pole SSR to power 5 two-phase 220V heaters.
My concern is whether it is acceptable to have one line with less load than the other two in the SSR controlling 5 heaters. Any advice or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated. Please add comments if you guys consider to add an extra electrical protection like fuses, etc.


what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

please add a link to the temperature controller datasheet ... add it into your question, not in a comment

(See How do I ask a Good Question?. Everything inviting useful answers is to go into the question "body". Stackexchange questions work best if there is a single explicit answerable question (I like it at the bottom of the post, and don't mind if it is the same as the title).)

(16 heaters 5 kW@220 V should be not much more than 71.4 kW@208 V. That would be before figuring in any voltage loss (wiring, SSRs).)

Strong recommendation - if not sure how to wire something linked to AC mains, get a professional help. This is no joke, people got electrocuted and stuff burned down. Please pay a professional and they will do it the way that it's done.

While this does not answer the asked question, this is true. The point is not "which wire must connect to where" but how to actually do the connections for the installation to be legal, and it might be illegal unless made by a qualified electrician. Electricians know what size and type of wire to use for a given length of wire and given load. They also know how to terminate the wires to make it safe, e.g. use lugs or ferrules, tighten the screws with acceptable tightness. And tie any cables down as required so the wires do not vibrate and come loose, etc. It's not enough to have a drawing.

sure, it does not a technical answer the question, but heath and safety is very important and there shouldn't be any guessing with this kind of wirering. That's why i think this is the only correct answer. I think i know how to do it, however i also think it should be stated very clearly that this should not be done if person doing it has no experience and adequate knowlade.

Yeah, but this is more a comment because it does not address the asked question.

Guys, I updated the question, thanks for the comments

(With 16 items the most balanced partition will have two parts of 5 and one of 6 - not one line with less load than the other two. At that power&imbalance level, I'd still not worry even with a line to line load leading to a PF<1. A local electrician should know where to look whether your contract puts a limit on PF and/or load imbalance.)
